# How can I delay the answer to a failed SMTP authentication in Exim?

Tags: smtp, email-server, exim, login

I run a small-traffic Exim mail server. Occasionally I do get illegitimate login attempts for `admin@DOMAIN` etc., which are answered with an `535 Incorrect authentication data`.

I would like to delay the answer to that authentication in the SMTP session, so that the adversary is trapped waiting for some time until the attempt is ultimately denied.

Exim has the very useful `delay = TIME` option, but it only seems to apply to Access Control Lists. To my understanding, by the time ACLs run, authentication is already negotiated (there is an `accept authenticated = *` condition, for which authentication must already have happened).

I would specifically like to delay the answer to a failed SMTP PLAIN authentication attempt. Is that possible in Exim?

Comment: For each stage of session its own ACL exists. CONN, AUTH, RCPT, DATA etc. Message may be rejected at any stage, all depends on your actual configuration.

Comment: I noticed that shortly after. :)  If you make this into an answer with a link to the according documentation section, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exim` provides separate ACLs for each stage of an SMTP session:

```
acl_smtp_auth       ACL for AUTH
acl_smtp_connect    ACL for start of SMTP connection
acl_smtp_data       ACL after DATA is complete
acl_smtp_data_prdr  ACL for each recipient, after DATA is complete
acl_smtp_dkim       ACL for each DKIM signer
acl_smtp_etrn       ACL for ETRN
acl_smtp_expn       ACL for EXPN
acl_smtp_helo       ACL for HELO or EHLO
acl_smtp_mail       ACL for MAIL
acl_smtp_mailauth   ACL for the AUTH parameter of MAIL
acl_smtp_mime       ACL for content-scanning MIME parts
acl_smtp_notquit    ACL for non-QUIT terminations
acl_smtp_predata    ACL at start of DATA command
acl_smtp_quit       ACL for QUIT
acl_smtp_rcpt       ACL for RCPT
acl_smtp_starttls   ACL for STARTTLS
acl_smtp_vrfy       ACL for VRFY
```

At each stage it is possible to check complex conditions and to make a decision to accept/reject/delay/route/etc the message. The action can be performed immediately or can be postponed for later processing with `$acl_m*` and `$acl_c*` variables.

Refer to [chapter 43 of Exim's specification](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-access_control_lists.html) for further reading.